# Code Coverage on Visual Studio Team System 2008 Developer Edition (on an NUnit application)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, nunit, code-coverage

Is this possible? I am looking forward to a tutorial which explains the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) has the ability to test (NUnit/MSTest/etc) with Team Coverage (which you already have since you have Team System : Dev).

Walkthrough: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2006/11/08/Driving-MSTest-and-Team-Coverage-using-TestDriven.NET.aspx) (you also get the coverage results window for looking at the coverage per method) - but this says it all:

[image: Using TestDriven.NET with Team Coverage]
<sub>(source: [mutantdesign.co.uk](http://www.mutantdesign.co.uk/weblog/images/DrivingMSTestandTeamCoverageusingTes.NET_F424/MSTestAndTeamCoverage_thumb1.gif))</sub>

You can use NUnit tests, but use the MS IDE integration for colorization, percentagaes, etc (no need for NCover). I use this all the time ;-p

The advantages are:

- no need to set up a "Test Run Configuration" (sorry, MSFT, but an own-goal there)
- fully integrated with VS (Code Coverage Results and Coloring)
- easy to use (just right-click -> Test With -> Team Coverage)
- easy to debug too (right-click -> Test With -> Debugger)
- easy to use the separate NUnit/NCover apps if you want  (right-click etc)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a tutorial](http://morten.lyhr.dk/2008/05/using-nunit-and-ncover-with-tfs-build.html) on integrating NCover with MSBuild.  [Here's a tutorial](http://blog.prokrams.com/2008/03/13/mbunit-ncover-and-teambuild-living-together-mass-hysteria/) on how to tell Team Build to fail a build when NCover reports code coverage below a minimum threshold.  To my knowledge there isn't yet a way to publish your NCover results directly to the TFS data warehouse, but I'd love someone to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

TestDriven.NET will also work very well with NCover. You can get some very nice html reports out of NCover, and you can integrate it with Nant.